# how to make li of ul width stretch the whole screen

Tags: html, css

I was wondering but I have been spending a lot of time trying to find a way to make my `li` from my `ul` stretch across but I seem not to be able to do it. It's very similar to the `nav` bar of [This website](https://www.verragio.com/) and [This website](https://www.jamesallen.com/).I am asking if someone can help me with this. 
Thank you. Best I can provide is a basic nav hover bar

```css
.dropdown-btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #d60d8c;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  border: none;
}

ul {
  text-indent: 0px;
}

nav:hover {
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar-tab {
  display: block;
}

.hover-list {
  position: absolute;
}

.navbar-tab-1 {
  background: #d60d8c;
  float: left;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-tab-1+.navbar-tab-1 {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.hover-list {
  border-top: black 3px solid;
}

.navbar-tab {
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-tab {
  max-width: 1240px;
}

.navbar-tab-1 {
  padding-right: 68px;
  width: auto;
}

.hover-list li {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border-bottom: 1px white solid;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-indent: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: 100vw;
  border-top: none;
  float: left;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 19px;
}

ul {

  

 padding: 0px;
   list-style: none;
   font-family: arial;
 margin: auto;


    }

      .navbar-tab-1:hover {
 color: black;
 transition-duration: .2s;
    }

    ul li {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    }


    ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
     color: black;
    }


    ul li ul li{
     display: none;
     transition-duration: 
    }




    .hover-list li:hover{
 background-color: #f5f5f0;
 transition-duration: .2s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown-btn">Go To...</div>
  <ul class="navbar-tab">
    <li class="navbar-tab-1 selected"><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <ul class="hover-list select">
          <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something you are looking for

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.dropdown-btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #d60d8c;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  border: none;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav:hover {
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar-tab {
  display: block;
}

.hover-list {
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  top: 66px;
}

.hover-list > li {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-tab-1 {
  background: #d60d8c;
  float: left;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-tab-1+.navbar-tab-1 {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-tab {
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-tab {
  max-width: 1240px;
}

.navbar-tab-1 {
  padding-right: 68px;
  width: auto;
}

.hover-list li {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border-bottom: 1px white solid;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-indent: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-top: none;
  float: left;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 19px;
}

ul > li:hover ul {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown-btn">Go To...</div>
  <ul class="navbar-tab">
    <li class="navbar-tab-1 selected">Test1</li>
    <li class="navbar-tab-1 select">Test2
      <ul class="hover-list select">
          <li><a>Item1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```